# Problema de cálculo javascript

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría hacer un cálculo en javascript en el cual si un autobus tiene 25 plazas introduzcas el número de pasajeros mediante un prompt y te calcule el número de viajes que ha de hacer para llevar a todos a su destino

```
let pasajeros = parseInt(prompt("numero de pasajeros"));
let bus= [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer el cálculo que requieres deberás utilizar lo siguiente

```
let bus= 25; //declaras el numero de plazas del bus
let pasajeros = parseInt(prompt("numero de pasajeros")); //pides la entrada de pasajeros al usuario
console.log("el número de viajes que ha de hacer son: "+pasajeros/bus);//realizas el cálculo y lo muestras por pantalla
```